# Loading tile zoom level 20

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, tiles

I have local tile also 20 level. I found out that OSM tile level 20 don't loading.

map code:

```
map = new ol.Map({
 target:'map',
 renderer:'canvas',
 view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center:[2577400.0, 7007400.0],
    extent:[2567000.5, 7000400.5, 2588377.0, 7014361.0],
    minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 20, zoom:14 })]
  })
});
```

and my osmLayer code:

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
       source: new ol.source.OSM({
       url: '../mapy/a_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
 })
});
```

Is there any problem with OSM level 20?
In browser devTools I have:

```
Request URL:http://server/mapy/a_tiles/19/295869/170467.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

despite I just loading 20 level ...

Anybody have any solutions, any ideas?

20-level zoom view:

[image: 20-level zoom]

19-level zoom view:

[image: 19-level zoom]

Comment: Can you create a full working example against the hosted version of OSM tiles. It is hard to debug something coming from a local server. And do you get any useful error messages in the console?

Comment: Are you using mapnik? mod_tile? Does level 19 work OK?

Comment: BradHards >> Level 19 work perfect. Level 20 work too, but instead tiles from level 20, increases tiles level 19 so I have fuzzy tiles. I see that tiles-20 don't load. But another wmf layer has changes resolution to 20-level. It seems strange - fuzzy OSM base map and clear another wms and wfs layers.                                                                                 I have added some sample pictures above.

Comment: **John Barça**  "It is hard to debug something coming from a local server" >> Yes I know that, but at my code everything is ok I just wonder if there are some barriers to display 20-level tiles OSM...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ol.source.OSM()` class has a [default maxZoom option of 19](https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html). If you would like to use zoom level 20, you would have to indicate this explicitly in your OSM layer definition.

In your case you would have to change this

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    url: '../mapy/a_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  })
});
```

to this:

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    maxZoom: 20,
    url: '../mapy/a_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  })
});
```